# FC.exe sin salto de línea mayor a 128 caracteres

Tags: windows, cmd

Resulta que hago una comparación de dos archivos txt y genero uno nuevo con la diferencia usando FC en linea de comando, pero al revisar el nuevo documento **new.txt** en las líneas que superan los 128 caracteres genera un enter o salto de línea. ¿Se puede aumentar ese límite de caracteres? ¿Existe alguna alternativa?

Esta es el comando que uso para generar la diferencia en new.txt:

`fc text1.txt text2.txt > new.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta función tiene ese límite y no se lo puede cambiar. Para ver todas las funcionalidades escribir en cmd:

```
fc /?
```